# cannot import spring project from github to intellij

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to import spring boot project from intellij but I have some errors:

[image]

```
Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.3.12.RELEASE' not found
Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:' not found
Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:' not found
Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found
Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found
```

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your pom.XML & errors as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for text content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Do you have full access to the Internet?  Do you have a custom `.m2/settings.xml` file in your home directory?

Comment: @mohamed abdelhamid elmansour Can you share the github link? Let me check it.

Answer (score 0):

try to use 2.7.2 or 2.6.10

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version> <!-- Or 2.6.10 -->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```